# Airflow setting up Google Cloud connection

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I am setting up a google cloud connection type in Airflows UI.  I am running Airlow 2.2 in docker locally.

I am adding what I understand are the required items for using a service account.  However, on testing, I get a 400 Bad Request.

```
 { "detail": "{'extra__google_cloud_platform__project': ['Unknown field.'], 'extra__google_cloud_platform__scope': ['Unknown field.'], 'extra__google_cloud_platform__num_retries': ['Unknown field.'], 'extra__google_cloud_platform__keyfile_dict': ['Unknown field.']}",
  "status": 400,
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "type": "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.3/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/BadRequest"
}
```

Looks like what the UI is sending is not passing validation?  Added both the config page and the response.  When 'saving' this saves without issues (no errors thrown) however, when navigating back to the page the updates are not shown.

[airflow config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dyw2.png)

[response message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayaYQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm what you did is working properly , just the test in Airflow is not working well.
after using this connection in BigQuery operators we could connect properly.
Airflow version: 2.2.5